# HTML5 Video button on top - Opera Browser

Tags: javascript, html, video, opera

I have video on my website and everything is ok in other browsers but when I checked it on Opera I see this button -> [image]

Is it possible to remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this: http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2016/04/opera-beta-update-video-pop/

To disable paste this in url bar: opera:flags#media-detachable-view